# How to configure two network cards on a hyper-v windows 2008 vm?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, hyper-v, virtual-machines

I have a virtual lan with three machines, all of them are Windows 2008 R2. First machine is Domain Controller, second has installed an SQL Server and third is a SharePoint host. I want this machine can connect to internet through a new network card. All virtual machines have configured an internal virtual network and SharePoint machine has another virtual network card configured to host cable.

The host lan gets IP using DHCP so I want to SharePoint machine gets a new IP by DCHP and get configured correctly to connect to Internet.

How can I do this?

Thansk in advance.

Comment: Sorry but your question doesn't make sense; could you carefully enumerate each physical and virtual NIC and what they're connected to?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a secondary virtual network with the new network card?
You can choose an external adapter when you make an virtual network.
And if you use dhcp on that new virtual adapter and on the internal virtual machine adapter it should work in my opinion.

Comment: I tried this but didn't work. Now, I think this was a problem that network connection was blocked by Hyper-V in someway. If this is the way I'll test it.